# Fragment 's onCreateView is called on API 17 and 18 but not on API 16 or older

Tags: android, fragment

I have an activity which layout adds a fragment:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" ...
<fragment  ... />
<TextView ... />
<ScrollView ... >
    <RelativeLayout ... >
        <fragment .... />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/namesFragment"
            android:name="com.myapp.NamesFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/xxx"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_names" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

After developing with a genymotion virtual device with API 18 I had errors on my actual device which has an older API. I noticed that `onCreateVeiw` is not called before `onPrepareOptionsMenu`, which cause the crush as some variables aren't set.

I've checked it with two "regular" AVDs. One with API 16 and the other with API 17. On API 17 `onCreateVeiw` is called is expected while on API 16 it is not being called.

Any idea why? *Did API 17 forces some default execution path or changed the Fragment's lifecycle somehow?*
Any idea how to "force" it, when the fragment is created by the layout?